# Specify where Visual Studio 2015 will look for header files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am developing a project in Visual Studio 2015 with C++/OpenGL and a couple of helpful libraries.

I have split my own code into two main directories: "/src" for all the .cpp files and an "/include" directory for all headers. The directory structure is the same for both folders, i.e.: All graphics related files either go into "/include/Graphics" or "/src/Graphics", depending on if they are source code (.cpp) or headers (.h)

[A picture of the project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eDNK.png)

If I want to "#include" a header file (which are in "/include" invariably), VS2015 will still look for header files in the "/src" directory. **And even though it doesn't find any, it STILL adds these folders to the list.**

[The #include list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h56rm.png)

I am aware that I can use brackets ("#include <>") to eliminate this problem. But the bracket list is already so crowded because of C++/VS2015 itself.

I already tried changing some project settings. Namely, I have added the "/include" directory under "C++/General/Additional Include Directories". And I have added the "/src" folder to "VC++ Directories/Source Directories".

**Question 1: Is there any way I can stop VS2015 from showing these "/src" directories twice in the include-list?**

**Question 2: How can I manage what shows up in the #include list and what doesn't?**

While it may be a feature, it is really annoying and serves no purpose in this case. Both list entries can be selected and they will work. I assume this is because VS2015 "figures out" in which directory the header files are actually located.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to add anything into `Source Directories`. All your source files are already part of the project while `Source Directories` could be used to deal with external code.

There is no need to add `/include` directory to `Additional Include Directories` or include them using `<>`, it would only make sense if you are developing header-only library. Typically when including header files from the same project one uses relative path, for example `Engine.cpp` can contain  `#include "../include/Engine.h"`. As you can see storing header files in separate folder makes including them somewhat ugly, so you may want to store corresponding source and header files in the same folder so headers can be included like `#include "Engine.h"`.

Note that Visual Studio provides "filter" view in Solution Explorer where you can still group header files and source files separately if you still want to do so.